# Accessing the registry through the .NET Framework shows 1 thing; Regedit shows another

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, screensaver, vb.net

I'm posting here because this question has nothing to do with how to program something and everything to do with a screwed up computer.

When I run the following line of VB .Net code in the Visual Studio 2010 Immediate Window:

```
MsgBox(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ProductName",                                               "SCRNSAVE.EXE", Nothing))
```

then I get the following message box:

```
---------------------------
Screensaver State Checker
---------------------------
C:\Windows\system32\PhotoScreensaver.scr
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

This makes no sense because the registry doesn't even have a SCRNSAVE.exe entry in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zlu6.png).

[image]

In fact, the current screensaver according to the Windows Control Panel is "(None)."

By the way, prior to this little exercise with VB .Net, I was having all sorts of problems trying to get the screensaver to turn on at the right times.

How can I fix this problem?

System Information:

- ThinkPad T400
- Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit edition
- More info upon request

Comment: Your screenshot isn't looking in the right place. You need to look at the `Product` branch.

Comment: To add to what Randolph said, your code is looking at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ProductName, but your screenshot stops at the Desktop key. Drop the "\ProductName" from the code, as your screenshot is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick S had the right answer:

your code is looking at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ProductName, but your screenshot stops at the Desktop key. Drop the "\ProductName" from the code, as your screenshot is correct.